# Websphere 9 start and publish speed is poor

Tags: websphere, rad

IN our localhost Rational Application Developer the start/stop/publish with Websphere has gotten intolerably slow with our recent upgrade to Websphere 9.0.0.5.  It often hangs after a line like this:

```
[2/13/19 9:17:01:404 EST] 0000006f SystemOut     O INFO  [com.ibm.kc.lucene.DictionaryBasedWarmer]- Searcher warmer is disabled due to missing 'dictionary.txt'.
```

But often even after it resumes putting out lines it just takes a very long time and will often give ThreadHung warnings because it takes so long.  We have plenty of memory (and in fact have increased the memory).  This slowness crosses over more than ten developers experiencing this.

Does anyone have suggestions to improve websphere startup and publish performance?  I tried the EnableCDI item I saw elsewhere on StackOverflow and that made my server unstartable.

Comment: Do you mean this property?
com.ibm.ws.cdi.enableImplicitBeanArchives=false

Comment: By setting the com.ibm.ws.cdi.enableImplicitBeanArchives custom property to false, CDI-related annotation scanning steps are disabled for archives that do not contain a bean descriptor, for example, the beans.xml file.

Comment: @jblye - Yes, I think that was the CDI property.  Turning that off forced me to rebuild my profile because WAS would no long start.  But I'm still looking for other ways to improve start and publish performance because this thing is just SLOW out of the box.

Comment: Maybe consider switching to WebSphere Liberty, is much much faster.